# JSON marshalling/unmarshalling an object that contains a list of objects (Java, JSON/Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I thought it would be a simple problem.

I have a simple structure, a class "Persons" that contains a list of "SimplePerson" objects. The Persons.java looks like this:

```
package jsontests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName (value="persons")
  public class Persons {

  @JsonProperty("person")
  private List< SimplePerson> l;

  public Persons(List<SimplePerson> pl) {
      this.l = pl;
  }

  public Persons() {
      this.l = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public List<SimplePerson> getL() {
      return this.l;
  }

  public void setL(List<SimplePerson> l) {
      this.l = l;
  }
}
```

And the "SimplePerson.java" looks like this:

```
package jsontests;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName (value="person")
public class SimplePerson {

  String name;
  String firstname;


  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * @param name the name to set
   */
  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * @return the firstname
   */
  public String getFirstname() {
      return firstname;
  }

  /**
   * @param firstname the firstname to set
   */
  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
      this.firstname = firstname;
  }
}
```

I use this code piece to create those objects and marshall them :

```
package jsontests;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class JsonListTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      JsonListTest var = new JsonListTest();
      var.run();
  }

  private void run() {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
      mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
      Persons cl = new Persons();

      SimplePerson first = new SimplePerson();
      first.setName("Schmidt");
      first.setFirstname("Peter");
      cl.getL().add(first);
      SimplePerson second = new SimplePerson();
      second.setName("Smith");
      second.setFirstname("George");

      cl.getL().add(second);

      String s = null;
      try {
          s = mapper.writeValueAsString(cl);
      } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

The result is as expected:

```
{
"persons" : {
  "person" : [ {
    "name" : "Schmidt",
    "firstname" : "Peter"
  }, {
    "name" : "Smith",
    "firstname" : "George"
  } ]
  }
}
```

To my mind it reads "we have an object called persons which contains an object called person. This person-object contains an array of objects consisting of name/firstname pairs." All this is completely OK for me and it is exactly what the code

Unfortunately what I receive from the costumer looks a little bit different. I receive

```
{
  "persons": [
     {
       "person": {
          "name" : "Schmidt",
          "firstname": "Peter"
        }
     },{
        "person": {
          "name" : "Smith",
          "firstname": "George"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

To my mind this reads a bit different : "we have an object called persons and this contains an array. The first and the second elements of that array are objects called person and they consist of name/firstname pairs.

Same same, but different :-) I spent one day to find a way to consume the input I got - and I was not successful. There would be no problem to change my class structures - there is very small chance to convince the costumer to provide a different JSON.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can create pojo very easily if you have json data -http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I would remove the root name from the Persons object and rename the list to "persons", then set alwaysWrap to true on the SimplePerson's root name annotation, finally disable the wrap root value feature on the mapper.

This way you may say: "An object with a collection type property called "persons" which contains (strongly typed?) "person" (type?) objects ..."

Comment: @Derick - thanks a lot - this really helped .

Comment: @Zsolt - I wanted to check that out but somehow my jackson artifacts version 2.6.4 don't seem to contain the alwaysWrap attribute for the JsonRootName annotation... thanks anyway!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I followed the suggestion of Derick (see first comment) and generated the data model needed. This seemed the best solution.

Comment: Your answer does not answer your question. I'm having the same problem but don't understand how I can use your answer to solve my problem. Could you please explain why Dericks comment helped and what changes you made to your code to get it to work?

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. It is quite a time ago... As far as I remember I just took the format that I received and generated the necessary POJO (instead of trying to write a POJO that will be dealt in the expected way).